# how to properly perform HTTP Post of a JSON object using C# HttpClient?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a very simple C# Http Client console app, which needs to do an HTTP POST of a json object to a WebAPI v2.
Currently, My app can do the POST using FormUrlEncodedContent:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;


namespace Client1
{
    class Program
    {
        class Product
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public double Price { get; set; }
            public string Category { get; set; }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             RunAsync().Wait();
        }
        static async Task RunAsync()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8888/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] 
                        {
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Category", "value-1"),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Name", "value-2")                           
                       });

                var result = client.PostAsync("Incident", content).Result;      
                var r = result;     
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I try to use JSON in the POST body, I get error 415 - Unsupported media Type:

```
class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}

var gizmo = new Product() { Name = "Gizmo", Price = 100, Category = "Widget" };
var  response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/products", gizmo);
```

Doing explicit JSON serialization does not change the outcome for me:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
var  response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/products", json);
```

What is the proper way to handle this, and to be able to POST JSON?

Comment: Do you own the server implementation? `415 - Unsupported media Type` is a server-side error where it's saying it doesn't support JSON, so unrelated to your client code.

Comment: Yes, My server side is an OData controller:  [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] Product value)
        {
            var req = Request;

            var p = value;
      
         
        }

Comment: Yes, but is your server project configured to accept and return JSON? Take a look at adding headers to your request to denote that you're sending JSON as well.

Comment: Just to confirm since I don't see it in the code that you're having a problem with, did you still set the media type like you did in the code snippet where it worked?

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

Comment: this client code still gives me 415:  var gizmo = new Product() { Name = "Gizmo", Price = 100, Category = "Widget" };
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(gizmo);
                var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("/Incident",  new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF32, "application/json"));

Comment: Change the client code all you want, the problem is on the server.

Answer (score 4):

When I am posting FormUrlEncodedContent this is the extent of the code I am using

```
        HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"grant_type", "password"},
            {"client_id", _clientId},
            {"client_secret", _clientSecret},
            {"username", _userName},
            {"password", _password}
        }
            );

            var message =
                await httpClient.PostAsync(_authorizationUrl, content);
```

where _authorizationUrl is an an absolute url.

I am not setting any of these properties

```
           client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8888/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

like you are.

Comment: Exactly. This is what I said in my answer below. But no idea why someone down-voted it.

Answer (score 3):

If you expect it to send as **FormUrlEncodedContent**, then MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json") is wrong. This will set the request content-type to json.  Use application/x-www-form-urlencoded instead or just do not set MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue at all.